# Invoking web service methods from code-behind

Tags: asp.net, web-services

The application on which I am working has a web service exposing various methods. Most of these methods use `WebOperationContext.Current` to set headers up to prevent cacheing. This works fine when the service methods are consumed in AJAX via the generated proxy, but when I attempt to do the same thing from code-behind, `WebOperationContext.Current` is null.

Can anyone tell me how to confer appropriate call context on the method invocation?

Comment: Hi Peter - why is it that your code behind needs to call a method of your own web service? If it's all part of the same project, you should put your business logic in a separate class file and have your web service methods call *that class*; that way your code behind can also call the class as well and you can refactor the code in the business logic to accept parameters for the specific information you require from HTTPContext.

Comment: It's legacy code that doesn't work. Management insists that I make this garbage work before they will leave me alone to do it properly. As a result it is important to make it work yet be so awful that they won't decide it's good enough and withdraw support for the next version.